# Consulta MySQL en Middleware Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

he estado tratando de realizar una consulta dentro de un Middleware en Laravel.
Mi sistema es para un control de inventarios. Cuando se solicita cierta cantidad de piezas de algún modelo, estas son sacadas de contenedores llamados 'Palets'.
Lo que quiero hacer con este Middleware es evitar que me deje inventarios negativos. 
Supongamos que necesito sacar 10,000 piezas del palet 5, pero únicamente tengo 5,000. El sistema actualmente me deja sacar las 10,000 pero me deja un saldo restante en el palet de -5,000 piezas.

```
<!--Campos de mi formulario que utilizo en el middleware-->
            <div class="form-row">
                <div class="form-group col-2-sm">
                    <label for="">Amount of pieces</label><br>
                    <input type="number" name="amount_Pieces" min="1" class="form-control-sm" value="{{old('amount_Pieces')}}">
                    {!! $errors->first('amount_Pieces','<span class="text-danger">:message</span>')!!}                    
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-2-sm">
                    <label for="">Pallet No</label><br>
                    <select name="pallet_No" class="form-control-sm" value="{{old('pallet_No')}}">
                        <option value="0">---Select One---</option>
                            @foreach ($MostrarPallet as $MostrarP)
                                <option value="{{$MostrarP->No_Palet}}">{{ $MostrarP->No_Palet}}</option>
                            @endforeach
                        {!! $errors->first('pallet_No','<span class="text-danger">:message</span>')!!}
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
```

La lógica consiste en lo siguiente: Si la cantidad solicitada (amount_Pieces) es mayor a la cantidad existente dentro de un palet (No_Piezas) entonces que me muestre un mensaje de que no contamos con la cantidad suficiente y por lo tanto no haga ningún movimiento.

```
    <?php
namespace App\Http\Middleware;
use DB;
use Closure;

class saldosNegativosPalets
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {

        $piezasPalet = DB::table('info_palet')
        ->select('No_Piezas')
        ->where('No_Palet_FK', '=' , $request->input('pallet_No'))
        ->get();

        if($request->input('amount_Pieces')>$piezasPalet){
            return redirect('/requisicion')->with('saldoInsuficiente','Oops...');
        }
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Para la consulta dentro del Middleware, utilizo el la tabla 'info_palet' y el campo 'No_Piezas' para saber cuantas piezas tengo en existencia y el campo 'No_Palet_FK' para consultar la cantidad de piezas disponibles en un determinado palet.

Dejo una imagen de mi base de datos de la tabla info_palet.
[image: BD]

No sé que estoy haciendo mal pero el Middleware me sigue permitiendo hacer que si la cantidad solicitada es mayor a la cantidad de piezas disponibles en un palet, sacar las piezas aunque me deje en un saldo negativo.

Aquí mi ruta

Route::post('/requisicion2','ControladorBDRequisicion@store1')->name('RE.store1')->middleware('saldosN');

Muchas gracias por su tiempo, espero alguien me pueda ayudar :D

Mi request

```
    <?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;
use DB;

class requestValidadorRequisicion1 extends FormRequest
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'request_No' => 'required',
            'amount_Pieces' => 'required',
            'pallet_No' => 'required',
        ];
    }
    public function withValidator($validator)
    {
        $validator->after(function ($validator) {
            // nota que cambié la query para que te devuelva un número y no una colección como lo estabas haciendo
            $cantidadPiezasPalet = DB::table('info_palet')
                ->where('No_Palet_FK', '=' , $this->pallet_No) // puedes acceder al valor de los inputs con $this->nombre_del_input
                ->sum('No_Piezas');

            if($this->amount_Pieces > $cantidadPiezasPalet){
                $validator->errors()->add('saldoInsuficiente', 'Oops... No hay suficientes piezas.');
            }

        });
    }
}
```

El controlador donde también inserto datos.

```
    public function store1(requestValidadorRequisicion1 $validadorEI)
{
    DB::table('info_requesicion')->insert([
        "No_Requisicion_FK" =>$validadorEI->input('request_No'),
        "No_Piezas_Movimiento" =>$validadorEI->input('amount_Pieces'),
        "Info_Palet_FK" =>$validadorEI->input('pallet_No'),
    ]);
    $validated = $validadorEI->validated();
    return redirect('/requisicion')->with('Exito','Datos guardados');
}
```

Comment: Creo que el lugar adecuado para hacer lo que quieres es en la validación y no en un middleware. Los middlewares son para aplicarlos a las rutas.

Comment: Claro, en mi ruta estoy aplicando mi Middleware. Cómo haría la validación? Soy nuevo en Laravel :c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como te decía en el comentario, creo que el lugar adecuado para hacer lo que quieres es en la validación. Entonces sería algo así:

[Form Request Validation](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/validation#form-request-validation)

Creas la clase que extiende de FormRequest

```
php artisan make:request Store1RequisicionRequest
```

La clase generada la encontrarás en el directorio `app/Http/Requests`.

Puedes agregar otras reglas de validación en el método `rules()`, puedes ver las que hay disponible [aquí](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/validation#available-validation-rules).

Pero yendo a lo que preguntas, puedes agregar tu lógica de validación personalizada en un "after" hook, usando el método `withValidator()`.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

class Store1RequisicionRequest extends FormRequest
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            // otras reglas
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Configure the validator instance.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Validation\Validator  $validator
     * @return void
     */
    public function withValidator($validator)
    {
        $validator->after(function ($validator) {
            // nota que cambié la query para que te devuelva un número y no una colección como lo estabas haciendo
            $cantidadPiezasPalet = DB::table('info_palet')
                ->where('No_Palet_FK', '=' , $this->pallet_No) // puedes acceder al valor de los inputs con $this->nombre_del_input
                ->sum('No_Piezas');

            if($this->amount_Pieces > $cantidadPiezasPalet){
                $validator->errors()->add('saldoInsuficiente', 'Oops... No hay suficientes piezas.');
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Luego todo lo que necesitas hacer es inyectar el request en tu método de controlador. El `FormRequest` entrante se valida antes de que se llame al método del controlador, lo que significa que no necesitas saturar tu controlador con ninguna lógica de validación:

```
public function store1(Store1RequisicionRequest $request)
{
    // El request request es válido...

    // Obtiene los datos del request validado...
    $validated = $request->validated();

    // haz algo con los datos
}
```

---

Para tu comentario:

> ...ya había leído que necesitaba que mi query me retornara un valor y no una colección pero no sabía como hacerlo :c Solo una duda. En la consulta para que utilizas `->sum('No_Piezas');`?

No hay mucha información de los agregados como `sum()` en la [documentación](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#aggregates), pero lo que hace básicamente es sumar los valores de la columna que le pasas como argumento. Lo bueno de esto es que no necesitas obtener los registros (o el registro) de la base de datos para luego tener el valor de la columna en cuestión, sino que directamente lo haces en la consulta.
El nombre de la columna `'No_Piezas'` lo tomé de la consulta que pusiste en la pregunta, pues supuse que es ahí donde guardas la cantidad disponible que quieres chequear.

---

Y para el comentario:

> También en mi código utilizaba esta linea: `return redirect('/requisicion')->with('saldoInsuficiente','Oops...');` para que me mostrara un alert y el usuario supiera que se están sacando más piezas de las que existen. Es posible adaptarla al código que me compartiste? De ser así como, porque efectivamente ya no hace la operación, pero el usuario necesita saber que esta sucediendo, por qué el sistema no lo deja pasar.

Disculpa ahí no había tenido en cuenta que usabas la clave `'amount_Pieces'` para mostrar el mensaje al usuario. Tendrías que cambiarla cuando agregas los errores al validador.
De:

```
$validator->errors()->add('saldoInsuficiente', 'Oops... No hay suficientes piezas.');
```

a:

```
$validator->errors()->add('amount_Pieces', 'Oops... No hay suficientes piezas.');
```

luego en la vista ya debería funcionar (puedes leer más [aquí](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#quick-displaying-the-validation-errors)):

```
{!! $errors->first('amount_Pieces','<span class="text-danger">:message</span>')!!}
```

también:

```
@error('amount_Pieces')
    <div class="alert alert-danger">{{ $message }}</div>
@enderror
```

o para mostrar una lista de todos los errores:

```
@if ($errors->any())
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
        <ul>
            @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                <li>{{ $error }}</li>
            @endforeach
        </ul>
    </div>
@endif
```

---

Y una última aclaración sobre el método en el controlador, que aunque no preguntaste, no está de más.

```
public function store1(Store1RequisicionRequest $request)
{
    // El request request es válido...

    // Obtiene los datos del request validado... NOTA: $validated serán solo los datos validados. Si no aplicaste una regla sobre algún dato, no estará aquí
    $validated = $request->validated();

    // si quieres usar todos los datos del Request, trabaja directamente sobre $request
}
```

Comment: Ya probé el código amigo y me resultó a la perfección, ya había leído que necesitaba que mi query me retornara un valor y no una colección pero no sabía como hacerlo :c Solo una duda. En la consulta para que utilizas ->sum('No_Piezas');?

Comment: También en mi código utilizaba esta linea: return redirect('/requisicion')->with('saldoInsuficiente','Oops...'); para que me mostrara un alert y el usuario supiera que se están sacando más piezas de las que existen. Es posible adaptarla al código que me compartiste? De ser así como, porque efectivamente ya no hace la operación, pero el usuario necesita saber que esta sucediendo, por qué el sistema no lo deja pasar. De Antemano muchas gracias, estuve unos días batallando con esto y por fín ya quedó gracias a tu ayuda :D

Comment: @HazaelM123 Cómo es un poco largo para los comentarios, agregué las aclaraciones a la respuesta

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo, lamentablemente ha ocurrido otro fallo :c Al momento de realizar algún movimiento las piezas de algunos Pallets les coloca otro valor. Ejemplo, puede ser que tenga 5 pallets pertenecientes a un mismo modelo de pieza y entonces si a 1 de esos 5 pallets les saco 1000 piezas el sistema también les resta a los 4 pallets restantes puesto que comparten el mismo modelo

Comment: Adjunto en la pregunta el codigo del controlador y request

Comment: No entiendo... Aquí estabas preguntando cómo evitar que te deje inventarios en negativo. No cómo restar la cantidad de un pallet y no de otros... Si lo que quieres ahora saber es cómo hacer la consulta para restar la cantidad en caso de que tengas la suficiente, deberías abrir otra pregunta con la información de cómo lo estás haciendo, el resultado esperado y el resultado obtenido.

Comment: Amigo muchas gracias por tu ayuda, tu aporte representó el 95% de la solución, en la query cambie el get por value y me sirvió. Mil gracias por tu ayuda, de vedad que no le veía solución a este problema. Tiene como un mes que quedó al 100 puesto que teníamos algunos problemas lógicos con los disparadores dentro de la BD. Pero de verdad agradezco mucho tu ayuda.